# Mysterious Disappearing Div on Secondary Click - Menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, web

I'm making a website template for my portfolio, and I stumbled upon a problem!

I have a menu, which shows when you click the '+' sign, and disappears when you click the '-' sign.

The problem I have is when I click to disappear the menu, the '+' sign appears and quickly disappears… I'll leave my Pen at then end so you can have a look.

I am using parallax.js and fullPage.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.menu2').hide();
    $('.direcional_frente').html('&#43;');
    $('.direcional_tras').html("&#45;");

    $('.direcional_tras').click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.direcionais').removeClass('margin_menu_direcionais');
        $('.direcional_frente').show();
        $('.menu').hide("slide", 400);
    });

    $('.direcional_frente').click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.direcionais').addClass('margin_menu_direcionais');
        $('.direcional_tras').show(400);
        $('.menu2').show("slide", 400);
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage();
    });

    $('.landing').parallax({
        imageSrc: 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/67567510/fundo.jpg'
    });

});
```

Here is the [Pen](http://codepen.io/angus/pen/yeqRwK) and the debugged [page](http://s.codepen.io/angus/debug/yeqRwK) for inspect element purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your [Pen](http://codepen.io/angus/pen/yeqRwK), JS line 11 you are hiding .menu (which contains the +), instead of .menu2

```
$('.menu').hide("slide", 400);
```

should be

```
$('.menu2').hide("slide", 400);
```

Answer (score 0):

> $('.direcional_tras').click(function() {
>           $(this).hide();
>           $('.direcionais').removeClass('margin_menu_direcionais');
>           $('.direcional_frente').show();
>           $('.menu').hide("slide", 400);
>       });

remove $('.direcional_frente').show();

> $('.direcional_tras').click(function() {
>           $(this).hide();
>           $('.direcionais').removeClass('margin_menu_direcionais');
>           $('.menu').hide("slide", 400);
>       });